# How do you add a string to a c# IList<string> from IronRuby?

Tags: c#, ironruby, dynamic-language-runtime

I get the following exception when I try to use a ruby script to modify a list of c# strings.

Unhandled Exception: System.ArgumentException: The value "Scott" is not of type "System.String" and cannot be used in this generic collection.

c#

```
IList<string> names = new List<string>();
names.Add("scott");
names.Add("jason");

ScriptRuntime runtime = IronRuby.Ruby.CreateRuntime();
ScriptEngine engine = runtime.GetEngine("IronRuby");
ScriptScope scope = engine.CreateScope();
scope.SetVariable("names", names);
engine.ExecuteFile("test.rb", scope);

foreach (var name in names)
{
   Console.WriteLine(name);
}
```

ruby

```
names.map! { |item| item.capitalize}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `to_clr_string` to the ruby code:

```
names.map! { |item| item.capitalize.to_clr_string }
```

Comment: ha I just came across your blog post when you answered my question here. - http://ironshay.com/post/ironruby-tip-ruby-string-and-clrstring.aspx