# Retrieving from resource dictionary via IronRuby

Tags: c#, .net, ruby, ironruby, dynamic-language-runtime

I have a Silverlight 4 app that contains a `Canvas`, which in turn contains a `Storyboard` resource (named `sb1`).

In C#, I can get to the storyboard resource by executing

```
Storyboard sb = (Storyboard)canvas.Resources["sb1"];
```

When I try to do the equivalent in ruby:

```
sb = canvas.Resources["sb1"]
```

I get a `System.ArgumentException` with the message

```
Key must be a Type or a String.
```

By itself, `canvas.resources` evaluates in ruby to `System.Windows.ResourceDictionary` so I expect it work like a dictionary...

Can someone point out what I am doing wrong here? I vaguely remember that there is a difference between a CLR string and a Ruby string.  Is that what happens here?

I am using IronRuby 1.1.3.0 on .NET 4.0.30319.235 with VS2010.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5341111/how-do-you-add-a-string-to-a-c-sharp-iliststring-from-ironruby):

> Add to_clr_string to the ruby code

I knew it was something simple. :-)